# How to compile OpenCV application with static libraries

Tags: c, opencv

**Preface**.
I wrote a small application in C that plays a video file with OpenCV library.
My Development machine is Ubuntu 10.04, but the customer's OS is OpenSuse 12.1
I've built OpenCV 2.1 by using cmake-gui and ensured that all required libraries were present (like described here http://www.shiffman.net/2011/01/23/how-to-build-opencv-static-libraries-mac-os-x/)
I've build my application with cmake-gui too (as described here http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Getting_started)

**Problem**.
It works fine on my computer. However, on the customer's machine I get "error loading shared libraries...". When I run "ldd video_player", it cannot find libavformat.so.52, libavcodec.so.52 and libstdc++.so.6. Is there a way to include these libraries with the player so that everything works out of the box?

**Epilogue**. I'm guessing there is a simple solution for that. However, having a strong background in Java and PHP, I'm a total newbie in C and the deadline is approaching quite fast. I tried to accomplish this task using ffmpeg, but it gave a lot of nightmares, so I just stick to OpenCV to make it work asap.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's typical:

```
LDFLAGS=-static buildcommand
```