# Using OpenCV installed on a system on a remote server- ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opencv, ubuntu-11.10, remote-server

I have asked a similar question but I didn't get much from that one.

I'm trying to compile C++ codes on a remote server. I need OpenCV library but its not installed on the server. Is there any way to use the libraries installed on my own system
to compile my codes?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and the server is also Linux based.

Thank you 
soroosh

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV binary deployment (Linux)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605363/opencv-binary-deployment-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to include the static libraries of OpenCV in your program. See this question  on how to do this: [How to compile OpenCV application with static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141817/how-to-compile-opencv-application-with-static-libraries)